# How to center align the text of v-select of vuetify components

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using the [Vuetify select component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects).
How do I center align text along with dropdown on vuetify?

Tried with text-md-center but that does not work

```
<v-select
   :items="['Lagna Kundali']"
   label="Rasi" solo
   v-model="firstKundali"
   class="text-md-center"
>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use vuetify slot:selection (tested in 2.3.10) so there's no need to modify CSS. Clean and easy:

```
<v-select
    :items="items"
    outlined
    :item-text="label"
    item-value="value"
  >
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
      <span class="d-flex justify-center" style="width: 100%;">
        {{ item.label }}
      </span>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by adding this css style :

```
.v-select__selection {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: For the "chips" option in Vuetify, this forces the width of the chip to be 100%, instead of just centering the chip.

Answer (score 0):

> Valid for versions before vuetify v2

Wrap your component in a [grid system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid). In the  `v-layout` component you can you specify `justify-center`. Please take a look at [example](https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/gqGvGO).

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap justify-center>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-select></v-select>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I doesn't mean to justify the whole v-select component but center/justify the text of v-select component.

The select text and drop drop menu item need to to be center align.
Sorry if i haven't clear the question.